# Routing algorithm

Tags: compiler-construction, routes, networking, network-protocols

I'm giving a presentation about computer routing and I want to make a good analogy with a real-world situation. However, I could not find it. Do you have in mind any of the situations like the computer routing. 
If yes, could you please provide me with it

Comment: 'Routing' is a huge area, what is the focus of the presentation? Postal routing is the closest to 'general routing'

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest the routing of international post as a very good analogy for the network routing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of (possible) real-world situations that correspond (more or less well) to routing in IP networks.

- Call routing. In the typical case. someone dials a phone number that can be broken down to an area code, one group of digits indicating a certain switch in that area code, followed by a group of digits that identifies the specific subscriber.
- Mail routing. Zip codes (or equivalent) has a prefix that allows the letter to be routed to the correct geographical processing centre (either directly or via another hub). The rest of thecode should be enough to route it to a specific mail route. It can then be routed to final delivery by the address (and possibly name) of the recipient.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the analogy of traffic routing (fixed hubs ie roundabouts and semaphores) lanes as network "roads", high availability lanes for emergency (same as high priority in packets).

This is what I can think about.

Answer (score 1):

Road traffic routing. Road signs and signals do the job of routing.

Answer (score 0):

How about the spreding of rumours? Some rumours are distributed only within social circle, more significant rumours are spread into other arenas.

The weakness of the analogy is that rumours are more akin to limited broadcast, while most network packets have specific target adresses.

Answer (score 0):

okey, i'll just suggest you a movie which is really helpful to give broad understanding of routing, proxy, firewall, packet addressing and intranet. Check [here](http://www.warriorsofthe.net/movie.html) (it's free) and use this movie to describe what you want.

The movie is about life of a packet and what happens from source to destination. it is animated by using some example in real life like vehicles carries the packets.

i hope you like it.